# How to call unbound method on object of subclass in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, reflection

I have the following classes in Python 2.7:

```
class Parent():
    def some_method(self):
        do_something()

class Child(Parent):
    def some_method(self):
        do_something_different()
```

Suppose I have a bunch of objects that I want to run `some_method` on. I execute the following lines (the first two are for the sake of this example):

```
c = Child()
m = Parent.some_method

m(c)  # do_something() gets called
```

Is there some construct such that in the last line `do_something_different()` gets called instead, without using any information about `Child` (as I potentially have many such classes inheriting from `Parent`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than using an unbound method object, use `operator.methodcaller`:

```
import operator

m = operator.methodcaller('some_method')

m(c)
```

This will look up the object's actual `some_method` method and call it. It's more expensive, but the extra time is all spent doing stuff you need.

Comment: That is very close to what I need! Is there a way of doing this if I only have access to the unbound method, and not its name?

Comment: found it, just call `m.__name__`

Comment: @Nibor: Note that the `__name__` might not match the attribute name. `Foo.bar` might have a `__name__` of `eggs`.

Comment: A method object doesn't have access to the attribute name, so it's not possible to do this right in all cases if you just have the method object.

Comment: okay, I can rewrite my code to just stick to the names themselves then. Thanks!